# Move values from table to another in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hello I have a PostgreSQL 9.1 database with such tables [tables are simplified]

[image]

For now I use only tables: account, account_word and word. But I wanted to add groups of words into my database. So I created tables wordgroup and wordgroup_word. Now my table account_word is no longer needed so I would like to move all words from account_word to wordgroup_word. In general:

**I would like to move all account's word to his wordgroup where group's "is_all" is true and then delete account_word table**

Could someone help me to achieve this?

Cheers

Comment: Grodek:  you can follow something as specified [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2973/how-to-insert-values-into-a-table-from-a-select-query-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move all words from account_word to wordgroup_word.

```
 insert into wordgroup_word 
    select  wordgroup_id, word_id
    from account_word aw join wordgroup wg 
    on aw.account_id = wg.account_id 
    and is_all=true
```

Comment: I will try your solution soon.